# Render a Google Calendar in my site from iCal feed

Tags: javascript, api, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to build an app that renders events into it's UI but I don't want to create a calendar UI from scratch if I can get something like the Google Calendar javascript API to do it for me.

So, like I am able to add canendar data (events, etc) into my Google Calendar account like this:
[image]

..can I also create a calendar UI in my own site with the Google Calendar API that is fed by my iCal feed, thus removing my need to reinvent the calendar markup/css? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can feed the iCal file to the API and get the UI out the other end ... you can input the iCal into Google and pull it out the normal way, but I don't know how that works with updates made to the iCal file being reflected on your site ...

Comment: Yeh I want to have this working isolated from a Google account